# Merge two arrays of pointers into a third array of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a program in C and I can't find out how to do the following. I have two NULL terminated arrays of pointers to strings, namely

```
char *tokens1[size1]
char *tokens2[size2]
```

I want to merge them into a third array of pointers to strings, namely

```
char **tokens;
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
char *tokens1[size1]
char *tokens2[size2]
char **tokens;

/* code to fill the *tokens1[] and *tokens2[] arrays with string values */

tokens = (char*) malloc(size1+size2+1);
strcpy(tokens, tokens1);
strcat(tokens, tokens2);
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: To be technically correct, you have arrays of pointer to char. C does not have a string type.

Comment: @chris, I believe we are to understand that this has happened in the commented region.

Comment: @cmh, Ah, I read that part as a prelude to the following section.

Comment: strcat/strcpy are for copying 'strings' not arrays of pointers

Comment: @chris. Agreed. Just trying to avoid future confusion.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to merely copy the *pointers* to the strings or create copies of those strings and store the *new pointers*

Comment: `char**` is not an array type. And what does "it doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 4):

You are copying pointer values, not strings, so you need to use `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`/`strcat`:

```
int i, j;
/* Find the current size of tokens1 and tokens 2 */
for (i=0; tokens1[i] != NULL; i++) 
   ;
for (j=0; tokens2[j] != NULL; j++) 
   ;
/* Allocate enough memory to hold the result */
tokens = calloc(i + j + 1, sizeof(char*));
/* Copy the arrays */
memcpy(tokens, tokens1, i * sizeof(char*));
memcpy(tokens + i, tokens2, j * sizeof(char*));
/* Since we used calloc, the new array is initialized with NULL:s. Otherwise we would have to NULL-terminate it like so: */
tokens[i+j] = NULL;
```

Comment: the pointer arrays are two NULL terminated arrays. so you have to copy `tokens1` till you find the NULL address and not copy the whole array

Comment: Or how about `tokens = (char**) malloc((size1+size2+1)*sizeof(char*));`

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck. indeed you have to use `tokens = (char**) malloc((size1+size2+1)*sizeof(char*));` instead of `tokens = (char*) malloc(size1+size2+1);`

Answer (score 1):

using

```
char *tokens[size1+size2]
```

and

```
tokens = (char*) malloc(size1+size2+1);
```

is not correct. . If you use the first one so you have already defined array of pointer with static allocation of `(size1+size2)` of string pointers. So you can not reallocate dynamically with malloc.

If you want to allocate dynamically an array of string pointer with malloc than you have to define `tokens` like that:

```
char **tokens
```

double pointer. which means pointer to an array containing pointers to string

and for the allocation you have do it like this:

```
tokens = (char**) malloc((size1+size2+1)*sizeof(char *));
```

for:

```
strcpy(tokens, tokens1);
```

you want to copy array of pointers to another pointer array. but you have used function to copy array of char to array of char. and the char type and the pointer type are not the same. the size of char is 1 byte and the size of pointer is 4bytes/8bytes (it depends on the system you use)

the same for `strcat`

The `memcpy` could not help you because you want to copy the `tokens1` array till you find the `NULL` address and not copy the whole array

If you want to copy only pointers (address) of strings: here after how you can do it

```
//to copy tokens1 (terminated with NULL address)
for (i=0;tokens1[i]!=NULL;i++)
{
   tokens[i]=tokens1[i];
}
//to concat tokens2 (terminated with NULL address)
for (j=0;tokens2[j]!=NULL;j++)
{
   tokens[i+j]=tokens2[j];
}
tokens[i+j]=NULL;
```

If you want to copy strings of `tokens1` and `tokens2` to `tokens` you can use `strdup()` function: here after how you can do it

```
for (i=0;tokens1[i]!=NULL;i++)
{
   tokens[i]=strdup(tokens1[i]);
}
for (j=0;tokens2[j]!=NULL;j++)
{
   tokens[i+j]=strdup(tokens2[j]);
}
tokens[i+j]=NULL;
```

Comment: oops I missed this `tokens = (char*) malloc(size1+size2+1);` make me confused

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: Sorry! I made a mistake. It isn't a static allocation of the **tokens** array. I want to allocate memory for this array with **malloc()**. I tried `tokens = (char*) malloc(size1+size2+1);` but I got the following warning from gcc: `assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Stavros so you have to remove char `*tokens[size1+size2]` and replaced by `char **tokens` : double pointers ;-). I will update my answer with this

Answer (score 0):

I just assumed that `memory` is well allocated for each `pointers`

```
    int i;
    for (i=0 ; i< size1 ;i++)
    {
     strcpy (tokens[i],tokens1[i]);
    }
    int j=i;
    for(i=0;i<size2;i++,j++)
    {
     strcpy(tokens[j],tokens2[i]);
    }
    tokens[j]='\0';
```

Comment: This is workable but it does unnecessary copying. Klas' answer is more efficient, because it only copies the pointers, instead of copying entire strings that have already been read into memory.

Comment: @TomDignan: Yeah you are right .. but I thought of implementing strcpy while solving rather thinking of memcpy